# How configure quantum 6056B thin client in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, configuration, lan

Currently using windows OS 64 bit with thin client technology. I want to switch OS to Ubuntu. How can I use same quantum 6056B thin client in same pattern. Please Help.

Comment: You gave few specific details; eg. no clue as to what Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? etc) or what release of that *unstated* product. I noted a PXE boot issue with one product/release (*and particularly fix available via specific ISO*), but you gave no specifics so if your intention was booting via PXE for example; I can't even provide any pointers.  Good Luck & give it a try on your actual hardware!  (*if you're using PXE there maybe boot issues for some ISOs but not others, with fixes available if you explore*)